# Validate and modify string passed to dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I'm building a predicate based on a string by using the System.Linq.Dynamic namespace and I would like to add some extra validations and formatting to the string provided by the user. To be more specific, I'm trying to avoid that the user has to type ToDate("2014/06/13") when he wants to provide a date in the string by identifying that the data type of the argument he wants to compare is DateTime and inject the DateTime() string around the date.

Code for getting the Lambda from a string:

```
 var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "Customer");
 var e = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<Customer, bool>(customFilter, p);
```

The only idea I came up with until now is to analyze the DebugView of the expression, get the properties, somehow transform them to types via reflection and do my logic from there. But it seems to be a bit complicated. 
DebugView:

```
  .Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Customer,System.Boolean]>(Customer $var1)
{
    .Call ($var1.CompanyName).StartsWith("S") || $var1.AttrCount >= 3 && $var1.ConnectionsCount >= 0
}
```

Does anyone have a better idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly is this `ToDate()` function defined?  Will DynamicLinq even parse that?

Comment: Ups... it's DateTime('string').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably going to have to pre-process the string or extend DynamicLinq to add support for date/time literals.  The latter is probably a better choice since the parser is already written; you would just need to extend it.

The reason I say this is because if you try to parse an expression like `it.Date >= "1/1/2014"`, DynamicLinq will attempt to construct a `>=` comparison between a `DateTime` property and a `string`, which will fail, as no such operator exists.  This effectively prevents you from rewriting the expression tree after the fact, as DynamicLinq wouldn't be able to construct it.

I've included a couple proof-of-concept solutions for extending DynamicLinq below.  I personally prefer the first solution, but the second more closely conforms to your original question.

---

#### Solution 1: Custom DateTime Literals

I just did a quick proof of concept modification to DynamicLinq that allows `DateTime` literals to be quoted with `#` symbols, e.g., `#6/13/2014#`.  It was pretty easy:

Add a `DateTimeLiteral` entry to the `TokenId` enum.

Add the following to the switch in `ExpressionParser.NextToken()`:

```
case '#':
    NextChar();
    while (textPos < textLen && ch != '#') NextChar();
    if (textPos == textLen)
        throw ParseError(textPos, Res.UnterminatedDateTimeLiteral);
    NextChar();
    t = TokenId.DateTimeLiteral;
    break;
```

Add the following to the switch in `ExpressionParser.ParsePrimaryStart()`:

```
case TokenId.DateTimeLiteral:
    return ParseDateTimeLiteral();
```

Add this method to `ExpressionParser`:

```
Expression ParseDateTimeLiteral() {
    ValidateToken(TokenId.DateTimeLiteral);
    string s = token.text.Substring(1, token.text.Length - 2);
    //
    // I used InvariantCulture to force a consistent set of formatting rules.
    //
    DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    NextToken();
    return Expression.Constant(d);
}
```

Add this entry to the `Res` class:

```
public const string UnterminatedDateTimeLiteral = "Unterminated DateTime literal";
```

---

#### Solution 2: Implicit Conversion of Strings to DateTime in Comparisons

If you don't want to have a special syntax for `DateTime` literals, you could  modify `ExpressionParser.ParseComparison()` as follows to simply detect when a `string` is compared to a `DateTime`, and parse the date at that point:

```
else if (IsEnumType(left.Type) || IsEnumType(right.Type)) {
    // existing code here
}
else {
    //
    // Begin added code
    //
    if (IsDateTime(left.Type) && IsStringLiteral(right) || 
        IsStringLiteral(left) && IsDateTime(right.Type))
    {
        if (left.Type == typeof(string))
            left = Expression.Constant(DateTime.Parse((string)((ConstantExpression)left).Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        else
            right = Expression.Constant(DateTime.Parse((string)((ConstantExpression)right).Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
    //
    // End added code
    //
    CheckAndPromoteOperands(isEquality ? typeof(IEqualitySignatures) : typeof(IRelationalSignatures),
        op.text, ref left, ref right, op.pos);
}
```

And add these methods:

```
static bool IsDateTime(Type type) {
    return GetNonNullableType(type) == typeof(DateTime);
}

static bool IsStringLiteral(Expression e) {
    var c = e as ConstantExpression;
    return c != null && c.Value is string;
}
```

Comment: What you're suggested sounds logical. Unfortunately I have no idea how to extend the DynamicLinq parser. I'll look into it and probably shoot another question at the community in case I don't figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: I'm looking at [the sources](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DynamicLinq/System.Linq.Dynamic/Dynamic.cs) right now, and it's just one big C# file.  Should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Since I had the sources handy, I tried adding date/time literals myself, and it took very little work.  I included the changes in my post.

Comment: Thank you very much! I started modifying the class myself but it would have taken me more time to figure out what everything does.